# Adding Pause at end of Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below works fine, until I tried to add a pause into it.  Basically, it will loop through and seem normal, but after a few times it sort of catches up to itself and causes a lot of strange reults.  I was curious if there is a better way to achieve what I am going for.

```
var popups = $('.animate');
var i = 0;
var pT = 2000;

function animatePopup() {
    if (i >= popups.length){
        i = 0;
    }
    popups.eq(i).addClass("show")
       .delay(2000)
       .queue(function() {
           $(this).removeClass("show");
           $(this).dequeue();
           if (i == popups.length) {
                setInterval(animatePopup, pT);
           } else {
                animatePopup();
           }
       });
    i++;
}
animatePopup();
```

Comment: Your best bet is to use callbacks. However, it may look confusing. It sure was for me the first time around. Have you tried setTimeout in javascript ?

Comment: `setInterval` runs every `pT` ms.. you probably meant `setTimeout`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`

`setInterval` runs the code/function in intervals, with the length of the timeout between them, but it **KEEPS RUNNING THEM**. On the other hand `setTimeout` runs once at the end of the specified time

Here's a snippet, if you change `setTimeout` back to `setInterval` you'll see it goes crazy too

```js
function recurrentDelayedFunction() {
  
    $('#out').append('ran<br>');
  
    setTimeout(recurrentDelayedFunction, 2000);
}

recurrentDelayedFunction();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id=out></div>
```